# Creating relationship conditionally with cypher (neo4j)

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I am attempting to create a linked list with neo4j, and have a root node with no relationships. Here is the pseudo cypher I am trying to create, but I am not sure how, or even if it is possible:

```
START root=node(1), item=node(2)
MATCH root-[old?:LINK]->last
WHERE old IS NOT NULL
CREATE root-[:LINK]->item-[:LINK]->last
DELETE old
WHERE old IS NULL
CREATE root-[:LINK]->item
```

Basically I am trying to insert a node into the list if the list exists, and simply create the first list item otherwise. Obviously you cannot do multiple `WHERE`s like I have done above. Any ideas how I can achieve this desired functionality with a cypher?

The docs solve the problem by first creating a recurrent `:LINK` relationship on the root node, but I would like to solve this without doing that (as you then need to create possibly unnecessary relationships for each node).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For anyone interested, I figured out a way to solve the above using some `WITH` tricks. This is essentially a solution for creating linked lists in neo4j without having to first create a self referencing relationship.

```
START root=node(1), item=node(2) 
MATCH root-[old?:LIST_NEXT]->last
CREATE root-[:LIST_NEXT]->item 
WITH item, old, last 
WHERE old IS NOT NULL 
CREATE item-[:LIST_NEXT]->last 
DELETE old
```

This works by first looking for an existing link relationship, and creating the new one from the root to the item. Then by using `WITH` we can chain the query to now examine whether or not the matched relationship did in fact exist. If it did, then remove it, and create the remaining link piece from the new item to the old one.

Answer (score 0):

For this, you might want to look at MERGE, http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/query-merge.html#merge-merge-with-on-create-and-on-match

And maybe at the linked list example, http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/cookbook-linked-list.html

Comment: I had looked at both those docs. As I said in my question, the linked list example requires you to first create a recurrent relationship which I wanted to avoid. `MERGE` would be great, except that you cannot perform a conditional `CREATE`.